# How to do a redirect in .htaccess without changing the URL bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I internally redirect a request to a particular page using .htaccess without changing the URL bar.

Example:
I want to redirect all 404 error to handle_controller.php.

I did the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) handle_controller.php?p=$1 [NC, R]
```

It's redirecting but  it keeps updating the URL bar.
For instance:

I request for invalid.php it redirects to handle_controller.php?p=invalid.php

How do I make it redirect internally to handle_controller.php while keeping the URL bar at invalid.php

I have used  R=301 and R=302 but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) handle_controller.php?p=$1 [L]
```

`[NC]` Is not useful when there is no text for comparison.
With `[R]` it's a redirection, without only a rewrite.